# How to get every 2 data value in an array list

Tags: c#

```
arraylist = [abc, def, ghi, jkl];
```

How should I use for each statement to get the output below:

```
firstdata = abc + def
seconddata = ghi, jkl
```

Comment: what type are `firstdata` and `seconddata`?

Comment: var firstdata and secondata.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure this is C#?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>();
int index = 0;
string newValue = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in arraylist)
{
   newValue += item;
   index ++;
   if(index == 2)
   {
      newList.Add(newValue);
      index == 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, The firstdata displays abcdef, the second data should display ghijkl.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to be 2 separate lists, you can do the following by `using System.Linq`

```
var firstData = arraylist.Where((a, i) => i % 4 == 0 || i % 4 == 1);
var secondData = arraylist.Where((a, i) => i % 4 == 2 || i % 4 == 3);
```

if you want the output to be a concatenated string, you can use `string.Join()`

```
var firstData = string.Join("", arraylist.Where((a, i) => i % 4 == 0 || i % 4 == 1));
var secondData = string.Join("", arraylist.Where((a, i) => i % 4 == 2 || i % 4 == 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x=1;
foreach(var item in arraylist){
    firstdata += item;
    x++;
    if(x>2){
       seconddata += item;
       x=1;
    }
}
```